# How to list all commits with gitlib?

Tags: gitlib

How to list commits with [`gitlib`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.3) in a similar fashion to `git log --reflog` command? So that it would list not only `HEAD` commits, but all commits that are there in the repository.

I have following code in Haskell:

```
reverseCommitLookup :: RefName -> ReaderT LgRepo IO ()
reverseCommitLookup refName = do
  maybeReference <- resolveReference refName 
  lift $ print $ T.unpack refName ++ " => "
  case maybeReference of 
    Nothing -> liftIO $ print "Cannot resolve the reference"
    Just ref -> do
      obj <- lookupObject ref
      case obj of
        CommitObj commit -> do 
          commits <- listCommits Nothing (commitOid commit)
          for_ commits (\commitOid -> do 
            ci <- lookupCommit commitOid
            tree <- lookupTree $ commitTree ci
            maybeEntry <- treeEntry tree $ BS.pack contentFile 
            case maybeEntry of
                Nothing -> liftIO $ print "No content" 
                Just entry -> do
                  content <- catBlob $ blobEntryOid entry
                  liftIO $ print $ (T.unpack $ renderObjOid commitOid) ++ ": " ++ (T.unpack $ commitLog $ ci ) ++ " -> " ++ (BS.unpack content) ++ " (" ++ (show $ (floor $ utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds $ zonedTimeToUTC $ signatureWhen $ commitAuthor ci :: Int)) ++ ") ")
        _ -> liftIO $ print "Not a commit"
```

It is able to output commits for a given reference. For example, `HEAD` or `refs/heads/master`, etc:

```
repositoryOptions :: RepositoryOptions
repositoryOptions = RepositoryOptions { repoPath = "data/.git" , repoWorkingDir = Just "data", repoIsBare = False , repoAutoCreate = True}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  repo <- openRepository lgFactory repositoryOptions
  runReaderT (reverseCommitLookup $ T.pack "HEAD") repo
  runReaderT (reverseCommitLookup $ T.pack "refs/heads/master") repo
```

What it is not capable to do is to output commits historically as they appear in `git` repository history as `git log --reflog` shows. For example, there might be other commits to other branches, not only to `HEAD` or `refs/heads/master` and I want them to appear in output at the time they were created relatively to other commits in *whole* repository history. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a gitlib expert, but I am a Haskell expert and I have taken a quick look through the gitlib haddocks. My conclusion is that this is a "patches welcome" sort of situation.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)